# Differences in float-content linespread with different positioning-parameters when using setspace

Tags: positioning, minted, setspace

I recently noticed, that the linespread of float-content changes, when changing the floats positioning parameters, while using the setspace-package. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minted}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=code,                           % Name der Umgebung
  types=codes,                         % Erweiterung (\listofschemes)
  float,                               % soll gleiten
]{loc}
\setuptoc{loc}{totoc}

\linespread{2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Code-Examples}
\section{Code-Example with H}
\begin{code}[H]
  \begin{minted}{python}
      class Wooo(Foo):
          def __init__(self, boo):
              self.doo = boo
              moo = 1 + 2 +3
  \end{minted}
  \caption{Beispielcode}
\end{code}
\section{Code-Example with hptb}
\begin{code}[hptb]
  \begin{minted}{python}
      class Wooo(Foo):
          def __init__(self, boo):
              self.doo = boo
              moo = 1 + 2 +3
  \end{minted}
  \caption{Beispielcode}
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: product]

Why is that and is there any way to alter this behaviour to consistently use the formatting of, for example, `H` positioning?

Comment: Can you confirm that you want the spacing with `hptb` to be the same as `h`? I posted an answer but think I misread your question, you want the spaces in the `hptb` right?

Comment: I don't neccessarily want a specific spacing. I want a generic way to make the spacing the same, if I use H, h, hptb or any other spacing, so I can just change the positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment about wanting consistent spacing, if you load `setspace` after `minted` it gives the compact version:

[image]

I have no idea why the spacing is different depending upon the float placement `[H]`, `[htpb]` so perhaps someone can elaborate on that.